# R: reshaping velocity profile

Tags: r, plot, line, reshape, rescale

I have the following velocity profile, which I have plotted using a velocity vector (y-axis) and a time vector (x-axis):
[image]
What I am trying to do now is to reshape the velocity profile so that I can have a new velocity profile where peak velocity is lower than the black line (1 SD lower). I used the `rescale`function and changed the range of values from min: `0` to max: `peak_vel - sd`. When plotting this new, rescaled velocity profile, I get this:
[image]
As you can see, both velocity profiles have the same total duration (aprox 1.5), which is physically impossible given that the red movement is slower than the black movement, and they both travel the same distance. What I need to do is to reshape (or rescale?) the slower velocity profile (the red line) so that the whole movement becomes slower, keeping the constraint of the peak velocity being 1 SD below the peak velocity of the black, faster movement.

Comment: Why is this *"physically impossible"*? The total space is smaller, that's all.

Comment: Why is that physically impossible? Two objects can travel at different velocities for the same amount of time. The slower object just won't travel as far. Do you want the two objects to travel the same distance? Then you need to scale the time units up as much as you scaled the velocity units down. That will keep the integral (I.e. the distance travelled) constant.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. It is "physically impossible" since they both travel the same distance, while their velocities are different. I will try scaling up the time units, as suggested by @AllanCameron, and see if this works

Comment: Quick question @AllanCameron:  if I scaled down the velocity profile using 1 standard deviation below peak velocity, what would be the equivalent in the time vector? 1 standard deviation above total movement duration?